# Automatisation of macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document and I want to do following with it:

1. Select some part of it when I open a Word doc (let´s say from page 40 to 45).
2. Reverse text in selected area.
3. Get text reversed again as it was before opening, when I close document.

I have this code, that reverses the text:

```
Sub ReverseSelectedWords()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oWords As Words
    Dim oWord As Range

    Set oWords = Selection.Range.Words

    For i = 1 To oWords.Count Step 1
        Set oWord = oWords(i)   

        Do While oWord.Characters.Last.Text = " "
            Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
        Loop

        Debug.Print "'" & oWord.Text & "'"
        oWord.Text = StrReverse(oWord.Text)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of that is?

Comment: To make text "unic" for some programs. If some person opens it, it should be readable for him/her, but this program will scan reversed (unic for itself) text.

Comment: And what do you suppose will happen if the user disables macros when opening the document (macro security settings might even do that automatically) or, once it's open, resaves it in the docx format?

Answer (score 0):

For what you've described as being your goal, it would make far more sense to apply a password for opening to the document and provide only the intended reader(s) with that password. No code required.